# How download an Excel file from website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

With this I can download an excel file in a local directory but I want download the file in the local directory of browser.

```
public void DownloadExcelFile()
{
//code
string fileName = @"D:\NewFolder\Test.xlsx";
oWB.SaveAs(fileName, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, missing, missing, missing, missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
oWB.Close(missing, missing, missing);
oXL.UserControl = true;
oXL.Quit();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using the Office Interop libraries in an ASP.NET environment. [Do not do this!](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757). Instead, use Office XML SDK, EPPlus, NPOI, or some other managed library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVC File result to returns filename like in this example:

```
public ActionResult DownloadExcelFile() {
   string fileName = @"D:\NewFolder\Test.xlsx";
   oWB.SaveAs(fileName, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, missing, missing,   missing, missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
   oWB.Close(missing, missing, missing);
   oXL.UserControl = true;
   oXL.Quit();

   return File(fileName, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "file.xls");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want download physical file use FilePathResult into MVC Controller

```
public FilePathResult DownloadExcelFile()
{

     var filePath = Server.MapPath("~/MyFiles/test.xls");
     return File(filePath, "application/xls", "FileName");
}
```